# AD User data not updating

Tags: user-profile-service, profile-sync

I have a User Profile Service, and the User Profile Synchronization Service is running. However, updates that I am making in Active Directory are not being shown in SharePoint 2010.

The UPSS was original getting stuck on 'Starting' and so I followed this procedure to get the service started:

http://sharepointdojo.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/how-to-re-provision-user-profile-sync-without-loosing-data/

Any ideas as to why the AD data is not being updated, I have given the account 'Replicating Directory Changes' permission.

Comment: I've had this happen a couple times. So the original sync brought in all the profiles? How are you verifying that they do not get updated?

Comment: In Central Admin people picker, I search for a user and all the user details are then. In my web-application I use the people picker and details are missing, specifically email. But the email is shown in the Central Admin people picker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the changes do not propagate to the web app. Go to the hidden user list and verify the email address is not correct:

```
http://sitecol/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx
```

..delete the user in question. Now to pull that user down again, you must add them to a group or grant permissions (You can delete those permissions immediately)

```
http://sitecol/_layouts/15/user.aspx
```

You should then see their email update in the hidden user list and people picker. Kind of a hack but it works for me when emails don't sync in my site.

Another thing that could be helpful (although I haven't tested this in a couple years). Is to view the UPA DBs. You can then run the delete command which will only delete the sync info, fire up User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization job again, and that should fix your sync issue:

```
Stsadm.exe –o sync –listolddatabases 0
Stsadm.exe –o sync –deleteolddatabases 0
```

Comment: That person does not exist in the hidden user list for some reason. Also I am on SharePoint 2010, so the /15/user.aspx does not work.

Comment: Turns out it was a single user, and we tried to replicate the problem with other users, and we could not. As soon as I removed the user from the 'hidden' user list, and re-added permissions for the site, the profile sync'd properly.